# LaTeX: Conditional execution of statement at a change of a variable

Tags: csv, latex

When reading from a `csv` file, the LaTeX package `csvsimple` updates the value of a variable, say `\location`, identifying a certain column.

I would like that the value of `\location` be displayed in the text, only when its value actually changes.

The following piece of code doesn't work.

```
    \documentclass{article}
    \usepackage{csvsimple}
    \usepackage{ifthen}
    \begin{document}

    \def\oldlocation{}

    \csvreader[head to column names,separator=tab]{input.tab}{}{%
       \ifthenelse{\equal{\oldlocation}{\location}}{\relax}{%
          \begin{center}\location{}\end{center}
          \element{}\\
          \renewcommand{\oldlocation}{\location}}
    }
    \end{document}
```

sample `input.tab`:

```
    location[tab]element
    Shelf 1 [tab] Item A
    Shelf 1 [tab] Item B
    Shelf 1 [tab] Item C
    Shelf 1 [tab] Item D
    Shelf 1 [tab] Item E
    Shelf 2 [tab] Item F
    Shelf 2 [tab] Item G
    Shelf 2 [tab] Item H
    Shelf 2 [tab] Item I
    Shelf 2 [tab] Item J
    Shelf 3 [tab] Item K
    Shelf 3 [tab] Item L
    Shelf 3 [tab] Item M
    Shelf 3 [tab] Item N
    Shelf 3 [tab] Item O
```

Expected output:

```
          Shelf 1
Item A
Item B
Item C
Item D
Item E
          Shelf 2
Item F
Item G
Item H
Item I
Item J
          Shelf 3
Item K
Item L
Item M
Item N
Item O
```

Comment: @Werner: Yes, thanks. Please, see edited question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem with your current setup is the update of `\oldlocation`. Using

```
\renewcommand{\oldlocation}{\location}
```

does not expand `\location` to its current meaning. It merely sets `\oldlocation` to recall `\location` when executed. This is fixed when using

```
\edef\oldlocation{\location}
```

The code below provides what you're after with some minor re-arrangements of the conditional code:

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{csvsimple}

\begin{document}

\def\oldlocation{}

\csvreader[head to column names,separator=tab]{input.tab}{}{%
  \expandafter\ifx\expandafter\oldlocation\location\else
    \begin{center}\location{}\end{center}%
    \edef\oldlocation{\location}
  \fi
  \element{}\\
}

\end{document}
```

You could have also used the following e-TeX conditional:

```
  \ifnum\pdfstrcmp{\oldlocation}{\location}=0\else
```

which compares the string expansion of `\oldlocation` with `\location`, and returning 0 of they are equal.

---

You may also consider using [`datatool`](http://ctan.org/pkg/datatool) for this kind of setup.